# INDEX to improve performance for View containing ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql-server, indexing, view

I have created the following view in SQL Server. It uses two sets of `ROW_NUMBER OVER PARTITION` queries within the view, as the two referenced tables will have multiple occurrences of the same `ServerName` over a range of `RowInsertDateTime` dates/times and I am only ever interested in the newest row of each table.

It is taking 4 seconds to return 471 rows. None of the tables contain indexes. I would like some assistance to understand what Indexes I might be able to add to improve the performance of the view. I have checked the actual execution plan, and two sorts are responsible for 11% and 35% of the total query cost.

The view definition:

```
CREATE VIEW ViewInSiteSuperTable 
AS
     SELECT 
         sales.ServerName,
         GETDATE() AS RowInsertDateTime,
         sales.daily_sales,
         basket.AvgBasketAmount,
         basket.AvgBasketQty,
         oos.OutOfStockCount,
         tph.transactions_per_hour,
         tph.total_transactions
     FROM
         dbo.InSiteEodSalesPerDayPerStore sales WITH (NOLOCK) 
     INNER JOIN 
         (SELECT 
              ServerName, 
              RowInsertDateTime,
              AvgBasketAmount,
              AvgBasketQty
          FROM 
              (SELECT   
                   ServerName,
                   RowInsertDateTime,
                   AvgBasketAmount,
                   AvgBasketQty,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY RowInsertDateTime DESC) rn
               FROM 
                   InSiteAvgBasketSize) q
           WHERE 
               rn = 1) basket ON basket.ServerName = sales.ServeRName
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT 
             ServerName,
             RowInsertDateTime,
             transactions_per_hour,
             total_transactions
         FROM 
             (SELECT 
                  ServerName,
                  RowInsertDateTime,
                  transactions_per_hour,
                  total_transactions,
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ServerName ORDER BY RowInsertDateTime DESC) rn
              FROM 
                  InSiteTxPerHourPerDayTotals) q
         WHERE 
             rn = 1) tph ON tph.ServerName = sales.ServerName
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.InSiteOutOfStocksAllStores oos WITH (NOLOCK) ON oos.ServerName = sales.ServerName 
    WHERE   
        sales.daily_sales_date =  DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

The execution plan

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indexes to eliminate 2 sotrs indicated are:

```
create index ix_ServerName_RowInsertDateTime on InSiteTxPerHourPerDayTotals
(ServerName asc, RowInsertDateTime desc) include(transactions_per_hour, total_transactions)

create index ix_ServerName_RowInsertDateTime on InSiteAvgBasketSize
(ServerName asc, RowInsertDateTime desc) include(AvgBasketAmount, AvgBasketQty)
```

However you should include the `actual execution plan` in your question, and not as a picture but using [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

> I understand basic indexes, e.g those to remove a table scan, but
>   would really like to understand the thinking behind these index
>   recommendations.

In this case indexes are not to remove the `scan` but to remove the `sort`. Both tables will be scanned anyway, you want to enumerate all the rows so you cannot remove the `scan`, but you want to enumerate within every `ServerName` group, and it is the first `index key`, and you want to order by `RowInsertDateTime` within every group, so it is the second `index key`. These two fields, when ordered, already have what you want: they are in order within s group.

Other fields are `included` as they need not to be in order but without them the index is not `covering` for your query, i.e. server will do lookups into the base table to get them because they are present in the `select` clause.

Comment: Thank you sepupic, I'll investigate your response. I apologise for not using Paste The Plan to paste my actual execution plan, however in my defense I was unaware of this sites existence until you posted it, so I am only able to do what I know to do. Now that I realise the site exists, I'll use it from now on.

Comment: Thanks - this worked. Query is now sub-second. sepupic, if you wouldn't mind talking me through the rational for how you arrived at these indexes? I understand basic indexes, e.g those to remove a table scan, but would really like to understand the thinking behind these index recommendations. That way rather than just copy pasting, I can 'learn to fish' a little by understanding how you arrived at these conclusions.